# What container product to manage and run Linux containers?

Tags: docker, kubernetes

The features I require are:

- Download Linux container images from an Azure container registry
- Build container images
- Upload container images to Azure container registry
- Store container images locally
- Run container images

The container image will run on one Linux server, the OS will be RHEL or Ubuntu. I don't think Kubernetes is necessary for a single server.

Should I use Docker Engine or are there any alternatives?

I require support, should I use a Mirantis product?